# windows phone 8.1 transparent tile

Tags: windows-phone-8

Can WP8.1 have the ability to create transparent live tile through code? In WP8, I create the background image of live tile through the WriteableBitmap. But the background of tile only have the theme color in WP8.1 similar to WP8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure that the file you're writing supports transparency (eg png) and that the source is transparent. I know there's a tutorial using writableBitmap and a user control. If you're doing something like that, make sure that the user control background is set to transparent.

Comment: Thank you! I set the user control background to transparent, but the background is always black in start screen no matter the theme color is changed(black or white).

Comment: You may have set background to transparent but I bet you are still using WritableBitmap and saving as jpg. Need to save in a format like PNG that supports transparency as Drew stated. Try this...http://toolstack.com/libraries/pngwriter there are 3 cs files you'll include in project and one extends the WritableBitmap. Then you can just do WritableBitmap.WritePng(IOStream); Tested and working in my app.

Comment: Thank you very much! I used the ToolStack C# PNG Writer Library mentioned by @Clarke76 . It works!